# Getting DNS queries to 73.207.210.75.in-addr.arpa

Tags: linux, dns

My Linux system is doing a lot of DNS queries to 73.207.210.75.in-addr.arpa but I don't know of any reason it should be doing this.  What is at in-addr.arpa?

Any reason why these queries are occurring?

Comment: This appears to be a comcast IP address. Since some process is querying for this via DNS, I would expect an outgoing connection as well. Does `netstat -an` show any on this IP?

Comment: all my netstat -an tcp connections are on localhost.

Comment: It may be a connection that's intermittent. You can use `nethogs` to see what applications are using the network. You could attack this that way. Also you could use `iptraf` to see what's accessing the network via that IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a totally normal `PTR` lookup for the IPv4 address 75.210.207.73 (which is the reverse of how it appears in your logs).

Its purpose is to resolve the IP into a name, *if* a `PTR` record was registered. This is the inverse of the usual name lookup which looks up a name in order to retrieve the IP address.

Comment: OK how do I work out what is making the queries?

Comment: @user43995 - you can start with `nethogs`.

Comment: Nethogs is showing this program as the sole network user "75.210.96.239:3389-84.232.246.36:4790".  How do I figure out exactly what is making the connections?  I don't recognize those IPs or ports.

Comment: I found out that running a "route" command from my code was triggering the PTR lookup.  Changed it to "route -n" and the lookup no longer occurs.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @Virgil - ha, there you go. Good sleuthing! I'd write that up as the solution to your problem, if you wouldn't mind. Others might benefit from this in the future 8-)